# How to integrate shape with dynamic chart in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, draw, shapes

I know, that we can add normal graphic shape in java to chartpanel from jfreechart, but, that if it is dynamic chart, which updates i.e. every 1 minute. Is easier way, to do this, than getting X/Y of some point from dataset, and repaint all graphics every 1 minute.
And there is another problem, when point of chart which declare one edge of i.e. rectangle, will hide behind Axis, after i.e. 30 minutes (if zoom shows litle part of chart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), may meet your requirements. It can easily keep pace when updated at one minute intervals, and it automatically displays only the most recent `nMoments`. This [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517440/230513) using `TimeSeriesCollection` retains all data added up to the limit specified in `setMaximumItemAge()` for each `TimeSeries`.

Comment: Ok, but, my question is about drawing and integrating with chart some java shapes, like rectangle. How to, dynamicly change shape coordinates while chart is updating.

Comment: Ok, I will try after, to paste here some code, or more about that what I need. I hope that will help to understand me :) (it's because my English is poor)